# SQL - How to roll up results into 1 row

Tags: t-sql

If I have a table:

```
ID NAME 
1  Red 
2  Blue 
3  Green
```

How can I return a query so that my result is:

```
Col1  Col2   Col3
Red   Blue   Green
```

Would I just do an inner join on itself or would I need a pivot table?

Comment: Did you tried pivot?

Comment: If it's as simple as your example, you could just alias your columns. If it's more intricate/dynamic, then you'd use a Pivot.

Comment: Can you show more data so that the query is not trivial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with join, eg:

```
select t1.name col1, t2.name col2, t3.name col3
from yourtable t1
join yourtable t2 on t2.id=2 
join yourtable t3 on t3.id=3 
where t1.id=1;
```

Or you can simply do it with embedded select statements, like:
In MySQL:

```
select
  (select name from yourtable where id=1) col1, 
  (select name from yourtable where id=2) col2,
  (select name from yourtable where id=3) col3;
```

In Oracle:

```
select
  (select name from yourtable where id=1) col1, 
  (select name from yourtable where id=2) col2,
  (select name from yourtable where id=3) col3
from dual;
```

Of course in that query the number of cols is fixed, you must edit it if you add more rows to roll up.

Comment: This works only with 3 rows and must add one libe for each row!!

Comment: Yes, this solution answers the join part of the question in case there are fixed number of rows to roll up.

Answer (score 0):

you can use dynamic SQL with PIVOT:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' +     QUOTENAME(id) 
                from yourtable
                group by ColumnName, id
                order by id
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

set @query = N'SELECT ' + @cols + N' from 
         (
            select id, ColumnName
            from yourtable
        ) x
        pivot 
        (
            max(ColumnName)
            for id in (' + @cols + N')
        ) p '

exec sp_executesql @query;
```